# Install button is showing disabled when I clicked on my apk file and showing modify or delete contents of your USB storage

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, sencha-touch-2

[image]

So, even the install button is showing disabled but when I lock screen and turn back on I see the same Install button active. This is happing every time. I just need to know the reason of this issue or any thing that can be done to avoid it.

Also my project was sencha touch and I am using android studio to generate the apk.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the sleep button of your android phone then click again to wake up the phone. Maybe then install button will work.